# getting two times like on my page when updating through update panel

Tags: c#, asp.net, updatepanel

I am implementing like and dislike on my asp.net page. Here is the `aspx` page

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="VotePanel" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="false">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <div class="row">
            <!-- left column -->
            <div class="col-lg-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                <div class="text-center">
                    <h1>
                        <asp:Label ID="LikeLabel" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
                        <br />
                        <asp:Label ID="DislikeLabel" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
                        <br />
                        <div class="btn-group">
                            <asp:Button ID="LikeButton" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-default" Text="Like"
                                OnClick="LikeButton_Click" /><asp:Button ID="UnlikeButton" CssClass="btn btn-default"
                                    runat="server" Text="Dislike" OnClick="UnlikeButton_Click" />
                        </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="LikeButton" />
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="UnlikeButton" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

this is my cs page

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;

public partial class Question : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    ConnectionClass cl;
    DataTable dt,dt1;
    string QuestonId;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            cl = new ConnectionClass();
            QuestonId = Request.QueryString["Id"];
            string[] var = { "@id" };
            SqlDbType[] type = { SqlDbType.Int };
            string[] value = { QuestonId };
            dt1 = cl.DatatableProcedure("GetQuestionLikeDislike", var, type, value);
            LikeLabel.Text = dt1.Rows[0].ItemArray[0].ToString();
            DislikeLabel.Text = dt1.Rows[0].ItemArray[1].ToString();
            dt = cl.DatatableProcedure("GetAnswers", var, type, value);
    }
    protected void LikeButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string[] var = { "@id" };
        SqlDbType[] type = { SqlDbType.Int };
        string[] value = { QuestonId };
        dt1 = cl.DatatableProcedure("InsertLike&getLikeDislike", var, type, value);
        VotePanel.Update();
    }
    protected void UnlikeButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string[] var = { "@id" };
        SqlDbType[] type = { SqlDbType.Int };
        string[] value = { QuestonId };
        dt1 = cl.DatatableProcedure("InsertUnlike&getLikeDislike", var, type, value);
        VotePanel.Update();
    }
}
```

When I run this page and press on like button, it implements it two times and like is incremented by 2.
Please help me with the solution so that the like is only incremented by one. That will be a great favor. Thanks in advance!
these are my stored procedures:

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[InsertUnlike&getLikeDislike]
(
@id int
)
as
begin
update QuestionTable
set Dislikes=Dislikes + 1 where QuestionId=@id;
select Likes, Dislikes from QuestionTable where QuestionId=@id
end

ALTER procedure [dbo].[InsertLike&getLikeDislike]
(
@id int
)
as
begin
update QuestionTable
set Likes=Likes + 1 where QuestionId=@id;
select Likes, Dislikes from QuestionTable where QuestionId=@id
end

ALTER procedure [dbo].[GetQuestionLikeDislike]
(
@id int
)
as
begin
select Likes, Dislikes from QuestionTable where QuestionId=@id
end
```

Comment: Why are you calling `VotePanel.Update()`  manually? Update will be triggered by the button click anyway, with that call you update it twice i think

Comment: @Anderi, i deleted this line from my code but still its working the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated my cs page to

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;

public partial class Question : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    ConnectionClass cl;
    DataTable dt,dt1;
    string QuestonId;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {cl = new ConnectionClass();
            QuestonId = Request.QueryString["Id"];
            QuestonId = "1";
            string[] var = { "@id" };
            SqlDbType[] type = { SqlDbType.Int };
            string[] value = { QuestonId };
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            dt = cl.DatatableProcedure("GetQuestionDetail", var, type, value);
            StatementLabel.Text = dt.Rows[0].ItemArray[0].ToString();
            MemberNameLabel.Text = cl.ReturnNameFromId(dt.Rows[0].ItemArray[4].ToString()).ToString();
            DateLabel.Text = dt.Rows[0].ItemArray[5].ToString();
            TagsLabel.Text = dt.Rows[0].ItemArray[3].ToString();
            ProblemLabel.Text = dt.Rows[0].ItemArray[1].ToString();
            LikeDislike();
            TriedLabel.Text = dt.Rows[0].ItemArray[2].ToString();
            dt = cl.DatatableProcedure("GetAnswers", var, type, value);
            drawAnswers();
        }
    }
    public void LikeDislike()
    {
        string[] var = { "@id" };
        SqlDbType[] type = { SqlDbType.Int };
        string[] value = { QuestonId };
        dt1 = cl.DatatableProcedure("GetQuestionLikeDislike", var, type, value);
        LikeLabel.Text = dt1.Rows[0].ItemArray[0].ToString();
        DislikeLabel.Text = dt1.Rows[0].ItemArray[1].ToString();
    }
    public void drawAnswers()
    {
        Label lb = new Label();
        if(dt.Rows.Count==1)
        lb.Text = dt.Rows.Count.ToString() +" Answer";
        else
            lb.Text = dt.Rows.Count.ToString() + " Answer";
        AnswerPlaceHolder.Controls.Add(lb);
        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl createDiv =
                    new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl("DIV");
            createDiv.ID = "createDiv" + i.ToString();
            Label[] l = new Label[5];
            for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
            {
                l[j] = new Label();
                l[j].Text = dt.Rows[i].ItemArray[j].ToString();
                createDiv.Controls.Add(l[j]);
            }
            AnswerPlaceHolder.Controls.Add(createDiv);
        }
    }
    protected void LikeButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string[] var = { "@id" };
        SqlDbType[] type = { SqlDbType.Int };
        string[] value = { QuestonId };
        cl.executeProcedure("InsertLike", var, type, value);
        LikeDislike();
    }
    protected void UnlikeButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string[] var = { "@id" };
        SqlDbType[] type = { SqlDbType.Int };
        string[] value = { QuestonId };
        cl.executeProcedure("InsertUnlike", var, type, value);
        LikeDislike();
    }
}
```

procedures to

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[InsertUnlike&getLikeDislike]
(
@id int
)
as
begin
update QuestionTable
set Dislikes=Dislikes + 1 where QuestionId=@id;
select Likes, Dislikes from QuestionTable where QuestionId=@id
end

ALTER procedure [dbo].[InsertLike&getLikeDislike]
(
@id int
)
as
begin
update QuestionTable
set Likes=Likes + 1 where QuestionId=@id;
select Likes, Dislikes from QuestionTable where QuestionId=@id
end

ALTER procedure [dbo].[GetQuestionLikeDislike]
(
@id int
)
as
begin
select Likes, Dislikes from QuestionTable where QuestionId=@id
end
```

and removed ChildAsTriggers property from update panel. It worked! :)

Answer (score 2):

Change your page load method as below,

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        cl = new ConnectionClass();
        QuestonId = Request.QueryString["Id"];
        string[] var = { "@id" };
        SqlDbType[] type = { SqlDbType.Int };
        string[] value = { QuestonId };
        dt1 = cl.DatatableProcedure("GetQuestionLikeDislike", var, type, value);
        LikeLabel.Text = dt1.Rows[0].ItemArray[0].ToString();
        DislikeLabel.Text = dt1.Rows[0].ItemArray[1].ToString();
        dt = cl.DatatableProcedure("GetAnswers", var, type, value);         
    }       
}
```

Comment: when i am doing that then the update panel is not working at all @Piyush

Comment: It should work. Can you debug and check whether button's event called or not?

Comment: please tell me what else i can do

Comment: Oh... so how like will be inserted

Comment: sorry but i debugged the code and every line got executed without repeating. I dont know why it is not getting incremented by 1

Comment: it worked with !ispostback but it worked after adding a function where laabels are updated. that function is being called from within !ispostback as well as after inserting like/dislike